# Required assets for Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter bootstrap for my mobile website.
What CSS and JavaScript files are required to use the following features?

1. responsive
2. navbar navbar-fixed-top
3. dropdown-menu

Are the following correct?

**CSS:**

```
bootstrap.css
bootstrap-responsive.css
```

**JavaScript:**

```
bootstrap-dropdown.js
bootstrap-transition.js
jquery.js
```

Comment: don't forget about the glyph icons!

Comment: Use the customizer to generate a custom bundle with only what you need: [http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html)

Comment: @DidierGhys Nice :).  You can make it as an answer or with your permission I can add it in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to add 
**`image`** folder.

- glyphicons-halflings.png
- glyphicons-halflings-white.png